# Deploying flask on an ec2 instance -- Max retries exceeded with url

Tags: amazon-web-services, flask, amazon-ec2

I have a simple flask app that I'm trying to run on amazon ec2. It's running on an Ubuntu server. For the moment I'm looking for the simplest possible way to get it running, even if it's not performant.  So I'm willfully ignoring gunicorn, nginx, etc.  I just want something simple to run.

Right now no matter what I run I always get the same error when I initialize a request:

```
HTTPSConnectionPool(host='my-ec2-address-at.amazonaws.com', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: / (Caused by NewConnectionError('<urllib3.connection.HTTPSConnection object at 0x7fd8b11a9880>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 61] Connection refused'))
```

I know this means I can't connect to the instance, but I'm honestly not sure why.

Right now here's my flask app (deliberately simple):

**FLASK APP**

```
from flask import Flask, request
import pandas as pd
import pickle
import json

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/', methods = ['GET'])
def view():
    return 'Hello World!'

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(host = '0.0.0.0', port = 8080)
```

I've also tried omitting the `host` and `port` from `app.run` arguments, as well as removing the `if __name__ == '__main__':` portion as well.

Right now my security groups for my ec2 instance look like this:

[image]

I'm basically trying to be as permissive as I can be for any possible port I think it might need to listen on.

I've tried several ways of starting the app, but whenever I check the request I keep getting the same error message.

Some commands I've tried:

```
FLASK_APP=api.api:app flask run -h 0.0.0.0 -p 8080
FLASK_APP=api.api:app flask run -h 0.0.0.0
FLASK_APP=api.api:app flask run
flask --app api/api run -h 0.0.0.0
flask --app api/api run
```

When I run these commands, it usually says that the app is running, but it does not seem to be accessible externally.

I'll usually see this in the console:

[image]

So, it's sort of running somewhere, but nowhere I can actually get to.

Again, I know you don't want a production server.  And I know there are managed hosting services.  But I'm doing this specifically so I can understand ec2 and running it on a more fundamental level.

My feeling is there's something small I have to change to get my configuration working, but I don't know what.

Comment: Have you tried to turn on the debug mode and setting `threaded` to `True`?
`app.run(host='0.0.0.0', port=5000, debug=True, threaded=True)`

Answer (score 0):

**Types of EC2 hostnames:**

There are two hostname types for the guest OS hostname when EC2 instances are launched in a VPC:

**IP name**: The legacy naming scheme where, when you launch an instance, the private IPv4 address of the instance is included in the hostname of the instance. The IP name exists for the life of the EC2 instance. When used as the Private DNS hostname, it will only return the private IPv4 address (A record).

**Resource name:** When you launch an instance, the EC2 instance ID is included in the hostname of the instance. The resource name exists for the life of the EC2 instance. When used as the Private DNS hostname, it can return both the private IPv4 address (A record) and/or the IPv6 Global Unicast Address (AAAA record).

**Example:**

- ip-10-24-34-0.ec2.internal
- ip-10-24-34-0.us-west-2.compute.internal
- i-0123456789abcdef.ec2.internal
- i-0123456789abcdef.us-west-2.compute.internal

References: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/using-instance-addressing.html#amazon-dns
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/ec2-instance-naming.html